# Animating OpenGL content within a Cocoa OSX Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation, opengl

I am currently attempting to create an interactive, informative poster, with regards to Anti-Aliasing techniques and effects. The application is written in Obj-C within Xcode, and makes use of OpenGL and Cocoa functionalities.

I am attempting to create a small animation to display the difficulties of drawing a diagonal line on a pixel grid, however am having real trouble getting my head around the animation aspect.

I am aiming for something with a similar look and feel to this: 
[image: Wu's AntiAliasing Algorithm GIF]

I have currently drawn a grid using OpenGL primitives:

[image: My rendered grid],
 and would like the effect above to be replicated within my grid, however without the shading yet (that is the next part), so just plain black pixels coloured step by step along the line.

I am new to both OpenGL and Obj-C, so am unsure whether best to implement the animation within OpenGL, or using OSx Core Animation - neither of which I have used before.

The OpenGL drawing takes place within my `MyOpenGLView` class, with the drawing done in a `drawAnObject` method, which is then called within the `drawRect` method.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!